# How to import dataframe from .py file to .ipynb file?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am trying to import a dataframe from funcs.py file to data.ipynb file, both are in the same directory

**funcs.py**

```
df_course = pd.read_sql('SELECT COURSEID, COURSENAME FROM COURSE', con=conn)
```

here conn is the pyodbc connection , it is working fine as i am able to view dataframe in funcs.py

**error**

When i tried to import df_course in data.ipynb it is giving me error, i am doing like this

```
import funcs.df_course as df_course
```

but it is giving me error that cannot import df_course from funcs

Please help me in this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use:

```
from funcs import df_course
```

because `funcs` is not a package, a directory that contains an `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import sys
function_path = r'C:\Users\hogsione\jupyter' # Path of funcs.py file
sys.path.insert(1, function_path)

# Now import df_course
from funcs import df_course
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead Of `import funcs.df_course as df_course`;

Use This:- `from funcs import df_course as df_course`

For The Name That You Want, `as df_course` is not necessary, but if u want to import it as `df` or something, then you can use `df_course`..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read this:
https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contributing/docs-contributions/getting-started.html?highlight=ipynb#edit-the-documentation-source-file

honestly, It's difficult to understand what you want from Jupyter notebook.
Did you use Jupyter? If yes, you have a file with extension .ipynb. but It's your code, it isn't your dataframe...